# Is there a good tour / tutorial for complete beginers on how to use ubuntu

Tags: discussion

Right now I am trying to help [this](https://askubuntu.com/users/301846/user301846) user solve [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493556) problem, and it is very difficult. They are obviously a complete beginer, and I am having to explain how to open gedit. I think their problem is very simple (wrong keyboard layout, caps lock etc) but there is no way to find that out as they can't use the computer properly.

Apologies if this is rude in anyway, please edit it to make it better.

Comment: by the way: don't think this is a topic for meta :D  More of a question I would ask in chat.

Comment: @Rinzwind yeah fair point :) just getting so frustrated...

Comment: you need to be newbie proof on AU :=D

Comment: For sure! I hadn't come across needing to be this basic before...

Comment: +1 to Tim for perseverance and patience.

Comment: This really isn't on-topic for meta, and I'm not sure it is a good fit for the main site atm. Don't worry about it though.

Comment: @BillGates, didn't work for me...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ubuntu-manual.org/ could be a start

Comment: Thanks :) Have given up on that one... If anyone wants to take over, good luck :)